# Is Python's Django WebFramework good to design Expert System as a Web App?

Tags: python, web-applications, django, python-3.x, machine-learning

I hope everyone is good. Well, I am at the end of my degree BS (Software Engineering), and in the third Phase of my Final Year Project named as 'Test Phase'.

My Project is to build an **Expert System for assessing programming course performance of e-learning students**. We are advised to **design it as a Web Application** as huge number of people will be using it online.

We are advised to **use Fuzzy Logic Algorithm of Machine Learning** while designing this Expert System.

Well, all of you might know that there is no match of Python when it comes to Machine Learning, so that's why **I selected Python Language** for my Final Year Project.

Now, I am confused that, should I use Django WebFramework to build this Expert System or design the Expert System as a standalone desktop application and connect that to internet? Confusion is here because, if I use Django, it will be same like a website like for example to access Expert System, we will have to go to following link:

*www.youruniversity.com/expertsystem*

This thing is confusing me, because how can an Expert System be same like a website?

Please help me in this confusion? Also, tell me according to the advice given by our university, is there any other way to create Expert System rather than using any WebFramework?

I shall be very thankful to all the helpful replies.

Regards,

Comment: 8 views and no help? :(

Comment: Please do not cross-post (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) - you've asked this exact same question on AI.se already. In general, web front-ends can be built for many types of applications, expert systems should be no exception.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner what do you mean by web front-ends? and I am sorry, I did not get response here so I posted there as well, should I remove one?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I deleted it from AI.se

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner is 'web front-ends' an another name for 'web apps'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web app is an application accessible through the web. One possible way of doing a web app is to have a front end (that's the part that presents the application for use in a web browser, including those parts of web server code that provide HTML pages and assets) and a back end which implements the logical functionality of the application.

In your specific example, the front end would be the web pages through which a user interacts with the expert system. This would include forms which are filled by the user with data for the expert system, forms to request details which were not initially provided, and web pages presenting whatever result the expert system comes up with.

The back end is the part of the server code that feeds the data from those input forms to the expert system (and most likely stores it in a database) and the actual expert system which would be totally unaware of being used from a web app.

Django can be used to build the form and presentation parts, as well as persistency. The expert system would be written without Django but using whatever AI system you decide to use. I would expose an interface that can be imported by the front end to be used in answering web requests.

I would advise to gain a little experience with Django and a very minimal (toy) back end to learn how to interconnect these parts, and replace the toy back end with a real expert system later.

Comment: Thank you so much @Hans-Martin Mosner, you cleared up all of my confusions. Thanks a lot again.